# Propagate trace_id on logback using Http4s

Tags: scala, logback, trace, open-telemetry, http4s

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to propagate the trace_id and span_id in my logback.xml file using http4s and Scala. Unfortunately, the variables appear to be empty.

To provide some context, I'm employing the OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/operator/automatic/) to implement tracing support over the http4s server.

Here's a snippet of my logback.xml encoding setup:

```
<encoder>
   <pattern>%highlight(%-5level) %-13(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %green(%logger{45}) TraceID=%X{trace_id}  SpanID=%X{span_id} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Despite my efforts, I've also attempted to change the variable names, such as trace.id, but the result remains unchanged.

Any suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I would try to reproduce it locally outside of any Kubernetes context. If you run your app with auto instrumentation locally, does it work? The [docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-mdc-1.0/library) also mention an Appender to be used, did you add it?

Comment: @GaëlJ Nope, no luck. I gave it a shot both locally and on Kubernetes with the instrumentation (as per your posted docs), and the outcome was unchanged.

Comment: What is the libraries used? OTEL specific JVM args?